# Vim crashes whenever I try to quit

Tags: vim, alacritty

So when I have a split open with a separate file, and when I do `:q` on any split it immediately crashes my Vim/terminal (They both crash, I think). But when I don't have a split open, I can `:q` just fine without any issues. I'm not to sure what to do other than, to just swap editors. I am using the alacritty terminal, and I have tried using CTRL+Q, from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478532/why-is-vim-frozen) answer, because I thought I hit CTRL+S by accident. But it didn't work.

Information about my vim:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Dec 12 2019 13:19:27)
MS-Windows 32-bit console version
Compiled by mool@tororo
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +channel           +cscope            +ex_extra          +iconv/dyn         +listcmds          -mzscheme          +profile           +sound             +termguicolors     +vartabs           +windows
+arabic            +cindent           +cursorbind        +extra_search      +insert_expand     +localmap          -netbeans_intg     -python            +spell             +terminal          +vertsplit         +writebackup
+autocmd           +clientserver      +cursorshape       -farsi             +job               -lua               +num64             -python3           +startuptime       -termresponse      +virtualedit       -xfontset
+autochdir         +clipboard         +dialog_con        +file_in_path      +jumplist          +menu              +packages          +quickfix          +statusline        +textobjects       +visual            -xim
+autoservername    +cmdline_compl     +diff              +find_in_path      +keymap            +mksession         +path_extra        +reltime           -sun_workshop      +textprop          +visualextra       -xpm_w32
-balloon_eval      +cmdline_hist      +digraphs          +float             +lambda            +modify_fname      -perl              +rightleft         +syntax            -tgetent           +viminfo           -xterm_save
+balloon_eval_term +cmdline_info      -dnd               +folding           +langmap           +mouse             +persistent_undo   -ruby              +tag_binary        +timers            +vreplace
-browse            +comments          -ebcdic            -footer            +libcall           -mouseshape        +popupwin          +scrollbind        -tag_old_static    +title             +vtp
++builtin_terms    +conceal           +emacs_tags        +gettext/dyn       +linebreak         +multi_byte        -postscript        +signs             -tag_any_white     -toolbar           +wildignore
+byte_offset       +cryptv            +eval              -hangul_input      +lispindent        +multi_lang        +printer           +smartindent       -tcl               +user_commands     +wildmenu
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME\defaults.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32  -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_TERMINAL -DFEAT_SOUND  -DFEAT_JOB_CHANNEL      -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /MP -DHAVE_STDINT_H /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG /arch:IA32 /Zl /MT -DDYNAMIC_
ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjCi386/ /Zi
Linking:
link  /nologo /opt:ref /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib netapi32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386   libcmt.lib  user32.lib          winmm.lib WSock32.lib  /PDB:vim.pdb -debug
```

It occurs with or without my `.vimrc`. Same issue occurs with Powershell, hyper, and cmd.

Comment: I know. I probably should've specified.

Comment: Vim version? on what OS? How did you get it? Does it happen with other terminal emulators? Does it happen with and without your Vim config?

Comment: You can check if it comes from vim extension. This is how you can run vim clean `vim --clean`.

Comment: @Nigredon I've ran `vim --clean` and it appears a plugin causes the problem. I got rid of the theme, and that solved it.